# Can't start rabbitmq-server

Tags: ubuntu, rabbitmq

Yesturday I've been looking for the way to increase the sending/receiving speed of my rabbitmq app and changed something so after 10 minutes my OS(ubuntu) said that there are only 100mb free diskspace. where are these files or folders I must delete?

And the more actual question is how to run rabbitmq-server. Previously it's been starting at the starting of system. Now it is not so and when I'm trying to start it as descrybed [here](http://www.rabbitmq.com/man/rabbitmq-server.1.man.html) and see the following in the console:

```
mikhail@mikhail-GA-880GA-UD3H:~$ sudo rabbitmq-server -detached
Warning: PID file not written; -detached was passed.
```

when I've tryed to do what is told [here](http://www.rabbitmq.com/build-server.html) I've received the following:

```
* Starting message broker rabbitmq-server                                       
* FAILED - check /var/log/rabbitmq/startup_\{log, _err\}
                                                                         [fail]
invoke-rc.d: initscript rabbitmq-server, action "start" failed.
```

In the log file is the following:

```
{"could not start kernel pid",application_controller,"error in config file \"/etc/rabbitmq/rabbitmq.config\" (none): no ending <dot> found"}
```

In the startup_err file is the following:

```
Crash dump was written to: erl_crash.dump
could not start kernel pid (application_controller) (error in config file "/etc/rabbitmq/rabbitmq.config" (none): no ending <dot> found)
```

**UPD:** I removed my /config file and something began working but not wel now when I'm trying to build server i get the following:

```
mikhail@mikhail-GA-880GA-UD3H:~/rabbitmq-server$ make
Makefile:372: deps.mk: Нет такого файла или каталога //no such file or catalog
python codegen.py body ../rabbitmq-codegen//amqp-rabbitmq-0.9.1.json ../rabbitmq-codegen//credit_extension.json src/rabbit_framing_amqp_0_9_1.erl
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "codegen.py", line 590, in <module>
    "body": generateErl})
  File "../rabbitmq-codegen/amqp_codegen.py", line 283, in do_main_dict
    execute(funcDict[function], sources, dest)
  File "../rabbitmq-codegen/amqp_codegen.py", line 258, in execute
    f = open(out_file, 'w')
IOError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: 'src/rabbit_framing_amqp_0_9_1.erl'
make: *** [src/rabbit_framing_amqp_0_9_1.erl] Ошибка 1 //error 1
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> {"could not start kernel pid",application_controller,"error in config file \"/etc/rabbitmq/rabbitmq.config\" (none): no ending  found"}

you have invalid config **no ending  found**

> IOError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: 'src/rabbit_framing_amqp_0_9_1.erl'

you don't have a permission to write to file, run make with `sudo` or change destination directory

Answer (score 9):

For reference, since this question and his answer are very well indexed in search engines, the message `(none): no ending <dot> found` means 2 things :

a) the config file is interpreted as erlang config file and thus should be valid in this language. This was the prefered way of configuring RabbitMQ before version 3.7.0+. ex:

```
[
    {rabbit, [{ssl_options, [{cacertfile,           "/path/to/testca/cacert.pem"},
                             {certfile,             "/path/to/server/cert.pem"},
                             {keyfile,              "/path/to/server/key.pem"},
                             {verify,               verify_peer},
                             {fail_if_no_peer_cert, true}]}]}
].
```

If you prefer new config format (sysctl format), please **rename your `*.config` in `*.conf`**

b) Since this is Erlang config file you must include a dot at the end (see example above)

source: https://www.rabbitmq.com/configure.html

Comment: Thanks! New to rabbitmq and didn't know about the two formats and the dot.